# ugarchroll with alpha = 5% return Error: plot-->error: VaR.alpha chosen is invalid for the object

Tags: r, plot, statistics, syntax-error, report

Hello everyone I had issue when run this :

```
aus_garch_roll_05 = ugarchroll(egarch_spec, data = data_new$Australia, n.ahead = 1, n.start = 2229,refit.window = "moving", refit.every = 10, calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = c(0.05))

report(aus_garch_roll_05, type = "VaR")
```

Everything is fine with alpha = 1%, when I change the alpha to 5% or 10%, the code return me:

```
Error: 
plot-->error: VaR.alpha chosen is invalid for the object
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Oops the code supposed: VaR.alpha = 0.5

Comment: but still return this error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format and all of the relevant code, including libraries. We have no idea what the variables `egarch_spec` or `data_new` are, nor where the functions `ugarchroll` or `report` come from.

Answer (score 0):

Well I forget to carefully read the this topic on R

We need to specify the alpha when print the report

```
report(aus_garch_roll_05, type = "VaR", VaR.alpha = 0.05)
```